# Add Visual Studio Code editor as a default editor in WinSCP when edit/view files in Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, winscp

How to add Visual Studio Code editor as a default editor in WinSCP, when edit/view files.

Answer (score 4):

In WinSCP:

- Go to *Options > Preferences*;
- Go to [*Editors* tab](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_editor);
- Click *Add* button;
- On [Add Editor dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editor_preferences), browse for `code.exe` of your Visual Studio Code installation. By default that should be:

  ```
  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
  ```
- Move the added editor entry to the top using *Up* button.

Answer (score -1):

[VS Code opens "VS" and "code" window every time I open a file from WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250763/vs-code-opens-vs-and-code-window-every-time-i-open-a-file-from-winscp)

In WinSCP:

Go to Options > Preferences;
Go to Editors tab;

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" !.!
```

Comment: Well, that's what my answer says already.