# VS Code opens "VS" and "code" window every time I open a file from WinSCP

Tags: visual-studio-code, winscp

How can I disable the option not to open `VS` and `Code` tabs every time I open a file in VS Code?

It only occur when I open from WinSCP a file on a remote server.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your [WinSCP external editor preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editor_preferences).

The command should be:

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" !.!
```

Nothing more. Nothing less.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_editor#vscode